# How to change content of a span based on Drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a select box and a label with a span, I want to replace span content as users change their selection on the drop down box.

```
<select class="text_select" id="field_6" name="field_6">    
<option value="- Select -">- Select -</option>  
<option value="Option One">Option One</option>  
<option value="Option Two">Option Two</option>  
<option value="Option Three">Option Three</option>  
</select>

<label class="form_field">Your selected <span id="aggregator_name"></span>?</label>
```

I'm using this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function notEmpty(){

var e = document.getElementById("field_6");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
document.getElementById('aggregator_name').innerHTML = strUser;

}
notEmpty()
</script>
```

Problem with this is, whenever I refresh the page, span is replace with "- Select -" but when I change the dropdown to another option, it doesn't change content of the span? 
Please help guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call your function from the change event of the drop-down:

```
document.getElementById("field_6").onchange = notEmpty;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mj4Vj/

Or, since you've used the "jquery" tag, the following replaces all of your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#field_6").change(function() {
        $('#aggregator_name').html($(this).val());
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Mj4Vj/1/

(Note: if the above is included in a script block that appears after the "field_6" element, e.g., if your script is at the end of the body, then you don't need to wrap the code in a document ready handler.)

Comment: You're welcome. But I don't understand how your update relates to my answer? (Note that when you have an id the selector "#field_6" is better than "select#field_6" - no need to specify the tagname when id is unique anyway.)

Answer (score 2):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/GEfwE/1/

Behaviour: when ever you will change anything you will see the cahnge in span,

Hope this helps, please lemme know if I missed anything! `:)~

**code**

```
$('select').change(function(){

    $('#aggregator_name').html($(this).val());
});
​
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use onchange.

```
var e = document.getElementById("field_6");
e.onchange = function() {
    var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
    document.getElementById('aggregator_name').innerHTML = strUser;
}
```